# Magento 2 Command Line Issue

Tags: magento2, command-line

Instead of entering each command individually is there a single commande that I can enter to deploy content and to also clear the appropriate folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could add a alias to your command line like so

```
alias deployit='php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy && php bin/magento cache:flush && rm -rf var/generation'
```

or you can seperate them

```
alias deployit='php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy'
alias cacheit='php bin/magento cache:flush'
alias genit='rm -rf var/generation'
```

its up to you how you do it but the above should make it simple for you to run the commands simply type in the alias